# How to make a BitmapImage fit the width of its container?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I'm trying to make a BitmapImage tag be as wide as its container, while scaling the bitmap. I achieved it using this code, which I think you'll find obvious:

```
<s:BitmapImage id='image' width='100%' source='assets/eyes.jpg' scaleMode="letterbox"/>
```

The problem I'm having is that under certain combinations of container width and image size, the bitmap doesn't show at all. I reduced the problem to discover that if I round up (or down) the height of the BitmapImage (using a timer, for instance), it displays perfectly. So I'm assuming the problem has to do with the height being some weird decimal number (although it does work with some non-integral heights).

Did someone found the same problem? I have code to reproduce it if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <s:Group id="grp" width="50%" height="50%" horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0" color="RED" >




<s:BitmapImage id="bmpImg" depth="100" width="{grp.width - 20}" height="{grp.height - 30}"
               source="@Embed('assets/image1.jpg')"
               horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0">
    <s:mask>
        <s:BorderContainer id="bmpMask"
                           cornerRadius="{sl.value}"
                           width="{bmpImg.width}" height="{bmpImg.height}" />
    </s:mask>
</s:BitmapImage>
</s:Group>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <s:controlBarContent>
    <mx:Form id="fid">
        <mx:FormItem id="fiid" label="cornerRadius:">
            <s:HSlider id="sl"
                       minimum="0"
                       maximum="{bmpImg.height/2}" />
        </mx:FormItem>
    </mx:Form>
</s:controlBarContent>
<s:Group id="grp" width="50%" height="50%" horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0" color="RED" >




<s:BitmapImage id="bmpImg" depth="100" width="{grp.width}" height="{grp.height}"
               source="@Embed('assets/image1.jpg')"
               horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0">
    <s:mask>
        <s:BorderContainer id="bmpMask"
                           cornerRadius="{sl.value}"
                           width="{bmpImg.width}" height="{bmpImg.height}" />
    </s:mask>
</s:BitmapImage>
</s:Group>
```